# Is tipping mandatory at restaurants in Canada?

Tags: canada, etiquette, tipping

Is tipping at restaurants mandated by law in Canada? Can a restaurant manager call the police if I chose not to tip?

I am not interested in any ethical or employment laws grounds. Just want to know if, as a customer, it is legal to pay the amount shown on the bill and leave.

I'm asking after reading [this question on money.SE](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/117963/is-it-principled-to-tip-less-if-a-pricey-restaurant-doesnt-accept-visa-or-maste) and related comments.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question about law and as such would be better suited to the Law stackexchange.

Comment: just because something might be on topic on another site doesn't mean it's off topic here.

Comment: @KateGregory it's a legal question, just because it mentions a country doesn't make it a travel question.

Comment: Other travellers, who have the same problem, will first look here since it is about different customs in different countries.

Comment: @MarkJohnson no, it’s not about different customs, the question quite clearly asks the *legal* status of tipping in Canada, not the cultural norm of tipping in Canada.  They ask if they can be arrested for not tipping.  That’s a legal question and not a travel one.

Comment: @Moo in most countries it is **custom** to tip peaple for good service (not mandatory or regulated by law) ; in some countries employees rely on tips because the employer assumes they will be tipped (also not regulated by law), for which income tax must be paid (which is regulated by law, but does not interest the customer) ; the OP (traveler) is askibg how this custom is delt with. And here is where others searching for that answer will first look how this custom is delt with. Paying the bill is a law question ; things not on the bill are not.

Comment: @MarkJohnson once again, you are putting words into the OPs post - they are not asking about customs or cultural situations, they are asking about the legal situation.  It’s quite plain there in the post.  “Is X mandated by law” is a legal question.  _“Am I obligated to tip in Canada through social, moral or ethical pressures or is tipping legally required?”_ is the question you are trying to insist the OP is asking, but that’s not what they are asking.

Comment: @Moo Since this is a **one time casual** law question conserning travelers, it should remain here since:
**Law Stack Exchange** *is a question and answer site for legal professionals, students, and others with experience or interest in law.* which the OP does not seem to be interested in as most travelers are not.

Comment: @MarkJohnson and questions about the law are on topic over there.  The OP mentions nothing about travel, the linked Money SE question asks nothing about travel, this is not a travel question.  Other than being posted in Travel SE, what makes the question as asked about travel?

Comment: @Moo because someone from Trieste, Italy who comes to Canada is a traveler and is asking about different customs there. As a member of law I would vote that off topic because these conditions are clearly show a travel topic. And thazt the topic is considered a custom is also meantioned there: **Tipping is not mandatory anywhere, it is only *customary* and I know that in North America that custom feels like an obligation but it still isn't one.**

Comment: Reminder: "be nice". Keep the tone of your comments polite.

Comment: I feel this question is on topic here, as locals will/should know the local laws but people traveling will not and this is a topic people traveling will run into.

Comment: This being Canada, the answer could vary depending on the the province.  The only regulations I found were about tip sharing and the like and, of course, the income tax treatment of tips.

Answer (score 5):

> Can a restaurant manager call the police if I chose not to tip?

No, once you have paid your bill you have fulfilled your legal requirement to the restaurant

- including any ['gratuity' entry](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/40550/95267) the bill may contain

Whether it is a good idea not to tip is another question.

You will find **very many questions** here on this topic that is specific to the United States and Canada, that are asked by Europeans, Australians and New Zealanders.

Many answers explain the reasons why, but more importantly how, when, where and how much one should give.

The [first question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/76048) given below contains a **Tips Statistics** which gives a nice overview for those unfamiliar with the topic.

The [second question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/149448/95267) gives a perspective from the **viewpoint of someone who works in the service industry** in one answer, but also answers about 'gratuity'.

Both questions, taken togeather, should give enough information about tipping in the United States and Canada.

---

**Sources**:

- [usa - How much to tip in the United States? - Travel Stack Exchange](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/76048)
- [usa - Can I refuse to pay auto-gratuity in a restaurant? - Travel Stack Exchange](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/149448/95267)

Comment: There is an exception, which is if a tip (Or service charge or gratuity etc.) Is advertised in the menu or elsewhere as part of the charge then it can be compulsory.